# Regular expression to transform 1.2.3 to 1.02.03

Tags: regex, transformation

i'm really not good with regular expressions and i need one to transform "1.2.3" to "1.02.03" in a way that first part stays always as it was and second and third one will transform 2 to 02, 7 to 07 and so on but if there is 10, 15, 17 and so on  it will leave it as it is. I want to use it in msbuild.

samples:

```
2.5.7  -> 2.05.07
2.10.9 -> 2.10.09
1.7.18 -> 1.07.18
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/\.(\d)(?=\D|$)/g  =>  .0$1
```

Works with any number of dots :)

**Edit:** when look-ahead isn't supported but word boundaries are, you can use

```
/\.(\d)\b/g  =>  .0$1
```

... or just because it's simpler :)

Comment: +0 But with a limited number of regex engines :)

Comment: True, added another using word boundaries

Answer (score 0):

```
/\.\([1-9]\)[([.$])]/.0\1\2/g
```

Starts with a dot, one number, dot or line end to dot zero number endsym.